# Android Studio PHP and MySQL User Login

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am making a Register User activity and login user activity in android studio however there seems to be a problem with either my PHP scripts or the java for the login system.

It was working for me for a while but then something broke, i got my backup running however, my scripts only return "invalid username or password" when it is entered correctly.

**Also, while i'm asking for help with this. This application is going to be a messaging/forum like application. Users will be anonymous for other viewers but visible to admins. 
The users will enter rooms like on whatsapp where they can write a message to a  group but with a reply functionality to each message.
And i began wondering whether i should use firebase for this sort of application where user register and login would be handled by firebase and also the messaging. Would it be possible to achieve this with firebase? Or is it a better approach using my own server and sql and so on....
 Could you give me any guidance towards what i should bare in mind and what i should think about using.**

The register user works fine, for now at least.
The full project and scripts can be found here:
https://github.com/Kraziion2/DatabaseApp2

scripts are called Android.

userLogin.php:

```
require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
        $db = new DbOperations(); 

        if($db->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
            $user = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['username']);
            $response['error'] = false; 
            $response['id'] = $user['id'];
            $response['email'] = $user['email'];
            $response['username'] = $user['username'];
        }else{
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";          
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

DbOperations.php:

```
class DbOperations{

    private $con; 

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

    public function createUser($username, $pass, $email){
        if($this->isUserExist($username,$email)){
            return 0; 
        }else{
            $password = md5($pass);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1; 
            }else{
                return 2; 
            }
        }
    }

    public function userLogin($username, $pass){
        $password = md5($pass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($username){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }


    private function isUserExist($username, $email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

}
```

java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
private Button buttonLogin;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
        return;
    }

    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logInBtn);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void userLogin(){
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                    .userLogin(
                                            obj.getInt("id"),
                                            obj.getString("username"),
                                            obj.getString("email")
                                    );


                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    obj.getString("message"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }

    };

    NetworkRequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == buttonLogin){
        userLogin();
    }
}
}
```

SharedPref java:

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {
    private static SharedPreferencesManager mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME = "mysharedpref12";
    private static  final  String KEY_USER_NAME = "username";
    private static  final  String KEY_USER_EMAIL = "useremail";
    private static  final  String KEY_USER_ID = "userid";

    private SharedPreferencesManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;

    }

    public static synchronized SharedPreferencesManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPreferencesManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public boolean userLogin(int id, String username, String email){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID,id);
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_EMAIL,email);
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_NAME,username);

        editor.apply();
        return true;

    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_NAME, null) !=null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public  boolean logOut(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }

public String getUsername()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_NAME, null);
}

public String getUserEmail()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_EMAIL,null);
}

}//end of class
```

Comment: Don't use `md5()` for passwords, better use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: use postman test your web service.